# How can I read a file and then add all lines to a String[]

Tags: java, arrays

How can I read a file and then add all lines to a string array in java?

Example:

Content from input txt file:

```
line1fromtxt
line2fromtxt
line3fromtxt
```

Output:

```
lines = {"line1fromtxt", "line2fromtxt", "line3fromtxt"};
```

Comment: `Files.readAllLines(Path path)`

Comment: you better use a List since you normally dont know how many lines the file has

Comment: Have you searched for it? I think there are enough questions or tutorials that tackle your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Files.readAllLines` to get a `List<String>` and then use `toArray` to convert that into a `String[]`

```
String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

And it would be simpler to use a List rather than an array.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename));
```